# php rename image saved from url based on csv values

Tags: php

currently: my code saves images from URLs given in a csv file.

**goal**: rename saved images according to values in the same csv file, and formatted by: csv positions 3,4,5,6,7,8

(e.g. 100A1_https://www.instagram.com/p/BBzUXUFLrGH/_48.8486557_2.3481125).

i'm trying to merge [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114310/php-rename-files-from-csv) example into my code. but unable to, as i am hopelessly lost.

```js
<?php

$destination = 'images/';
$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dir = "dir to photos";

$row = 0;

if (($handle = fopen("data/testcsvfile.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 100, ",")) !== FALSE /*&& $row < 1*/) {
    $row++;

    // number of fields in each row
    $num = count($data);

    // get url from position in csv
    $url = $data[6];
    echo $row . " " . $url. PHP_EOL;

    if( strlen($url) > 0 ){
        // if we have a url, get the contents
        $page = file_get_contents($url);
        //echo $page;

        $dom->loadHTML($page);

        // find url using meta tag
        $my_tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('meta');

        // find which one is the image and grab and save
        foreach ($my_tags as $tag) {
            if($tag->getAttribute("property") == "og:image"){
                $image_url = $tag->getAttribute('content');
                echo  $image_url . PHP_EOL;
                $the_image = file_get_contents($image_url);

                // rename file based on csv
                // $newname = "$dir"."$names[3] $names[4] $names[5]".";
                rename($newname);


                file_put_contents( $destination . "img_" . $row . ".jpg", $the_image);

            }

        }

    }

  }
  fclose($handle);
}

?>
```

```css
// test csv file

Mon,1,0,100,A,1,https://www.instagram.com/p/BBzUXUFLrGH/,48.8486557,2.3481125
Mon,1,0,100,A,1,https://www.instagram.com/p/BAe0tGULrC1/,48.85272468,2.347259349
Mon,1,0,100,A,1,https://www.instagram.com/p/_zik5YLrMf/,48.85356691,2.345645975
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly: are you trying to rename the file fetched from `https://www.instagram.com/p/BBzUXUFLrGH/` to `100A1_https://www.instagram.com/p/BBzUXUFLrGH/_48.8486557_2.3481125` ?

Comment: exactly. images are currently being saved by a random computer-generated naming convention (e.g. img_1) that has nothing to do with the csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to understand that using an URL as a filename is a very strange/bad thing.
An URL uses special chars like '/' that are directory separators in some OSs.
If you really need to do this you need first to escape that character in the filename (or better replace them with non special characters like an underscore):

```
$newname = str_replace('/', '\/', $newname);
```

An updated version of your script with safe substitution of the slashes with underscores:

```
<?php

$destination = 'images';
$dom = new DOMDocument;

if (($handle = fopen("data/testcsvfile.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 100, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);

    // get url from position in csv
    $url = $data[6];
    echo $row . " " . $url. PHP_EOL;

    if( strlen($url) > 0 ){
        // if we have a url, get the contents
        $page = file_get_contents($url);
        //echo $page;

        $dom->loadHTML($page);

        // find url using meta tag
        $my_tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('meta');

        // find which one is the image and grab and save
        foreach ($my_tags as $tag) {
            if($tag->getAttribute("property") == "og:image"){
                $image_url = $tag->getAttribute('content');
                echo  $image_url . PHP_EOL;
                $the_image = file_get_contents($image_url);

                $destinationName = str_replace('/', '_', sprintf(
                  "%s%s%s_%s_%s_%s",
                  $data[3],
                  $data[4],
                  $data[5],
                  $data[6],
                  $data[7],
                  $data[8]
                ));

                $destinationPath = sprintf(
                  "%s/%s",
                  $destination,
                  $destinationName
                );


                file_put_contents($destinationPath, $the_image);

            }

        }

    }

  }
  fclose($handle);
}

?>
```

Comment: cool, thanks! eventually, i have to plot these images on a map and have each image correspond to its respective hyperlink. i wasn't sure the best way to go about it. i guess i can forego the hyperlink and re-associate it in a different way.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a functional code. If you cant use a DB (but think about sqlite in this case) you can go for a sustitution of the slashes with an other character that you will then re-susbst with the original slash to obtain the origin URL

Comment: wow, this is amazing. thank you so much! i'll take a look at sqlite. thanks again!